# Creating a database using PDO returning syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to learn PHP and as part of this am writing a small setup script. I have written one before and it worked, however, I have now written a multistage `setup.php` script and am getting a syntax error when executing the following prepared MySQL statement:

```
$sql = $connection->prepare( "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ?" );
$sql->execute( array( $database_name ) );
```

Where `$database_name` is provided by a form. I have done a `var_dump` on `$database_name` and it has the value I provide to it by the form. However, when executing the statement, I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "cv_database" at line 1

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: You can't use parameters for MYSQL identifiers like table or column names

Comment: Perhaps you can't use wildcards for database names?

Comment: Share the db name you provided through the form.

Comment: Are you doing it on an online web server? Then I think they don't provide provision to create database via code.

Comment: @RocketSurgeon I gave it "cv_database", is that what you're asking for?

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran No, I'm doing it on my local machine using Desktop Server, and I know that it works if I just use `$connection->exec( "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $database_name );` but I thought that using prepared statements would be safer.

Comment: @Shaktal That's the only way you can create this sort of query. Be sure to sanitize & escape the user-supplied string before inserting it into your query.

Comment: Yeah @HoboSapiens seems to be right. You can't use placeholders for  database name, table names, column names in PDO. The answer here also mentions the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988935/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064

Comment: @HoboSapiens I have tried the following and am getting the same syntax error? `$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $connection->quote( $database_name );
     $connection->exec( $sql );`